# Emulating ActionScript 3.0 / JavaScript DateTime in Java

Tags: java, javascript, android, actionscript-3, ecma262

I'm looking to port some DateTime functionality from ActionScript 3.0 over to Java/Android. I am currently looking at Joda. Before going with this option I wonder if there are actually any implementations of the DateTime object with ECMA-262 3rd Edition compliance? Or is there a better option (smaller/lightweight) solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully emulate the DateTime object in Java on Android using Joda